# How to get specific lambda metric statistics, like iteratorAge using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get specific lambda cloudwatch monitor metrics but not am not sure how to go about this. For example, I'd like to get iterator age statistics between start and end date for lambda named "publish_data".

I tried the following:

public GetMetricStatisticsRequest getMetricStatisticsRequest(Date startTime, Date endTime,String metricName){

```
GetMetricStatisticsRequest statisticsRequest = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
        .withStartTime(startTime)
        .withEndTime(endTime)
        .withMetricName("iteratorAge");
```

Obviously metric name needs to relate to a specific lambda function which I cant understand how to set.

**EDIT:**

So I understand I need to use dimensions in order to choose a particular metric within from a particular Lambda function, yet I am unable to find a way to do it.

So for example I have a Lambda function called publish_data and the metric is iteratorAge, I tried the following:

```
Dimension dimensions = new Dimension();   
 dimensions.withName("FunctionName").withValue("publish_data").withName("Metric Name").withValue("iteratorAge");
```

Doesnt work... I took the exact same key string (withname) values from the cloudwatch AWS console but didnt specify to look specifically at lambda as I am not sure how to do that. (I just straight to lambda function and metric name)

Anyone? :)

Comment: You'll need to call `.WithDimensions()` and pass the dimension that sets the lambda name.  Check in the Cloudwatch UI if you're having trouble finding it.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for example of how to use Dimensions in that context but couldn't find it.